# Execute java instance method via terminal

Tags: java, reflection, terminal, program-entry-point

I have an instance. Basic structure is ;

```
class Instance{

    public void load(){
        ...
    }

    public boolean execute(){
        ...
        return true;
    }

}
```

As normally we can execute this instance in `static void main(String args[])` but how can we execute this instance -> `load()` -> `execute()` from terminal or compiled file `.class` is called within a `main` method than using reflection to execute defined methods.

Because this instance acts like a script on out project, but we do not define main function into class.

Anyone helps?

Comment: You can't. You can pass in a string "execute" or "load" as an argument and call the method from your main method based on the string that's passed in as the argument.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend simply adding a `public static void main(String args[])` that calls `load()` and `execute()` so that your class can be executed from the command line in the usual way. There is little point in over-complicating the problem by building a reflection-based wrapper that will just need its own `public static void main(String args[])` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> how can we execute this instance -> load() -> execute() from terminal

You can't.

It'll probably be [implemented in Java 9](https://blogs.oracle.com/java/jshell-and-repl-in-java-9), but for now there is no official way to run methods from the command line.

> or compiled file .class is called within a main method than using reflection

As you said, use reflection:

```
File pathToClass = new File("C:\\Some Folder\\");

Class<?> loaded = null;
try {
    ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {pathToClass.toURL()});
    loaded = loader.loadClass("some.package.foo.Instance");
} catch(Exception e) {
    //do something
}

Object i = loaded.newInstance();
Method method = loaded.getMethod("execute");
Boolean returnValue = (Boolean) method.invoke(i);
```

I'd recommend not doing this though - there's usually a better way and it just overcomplicates everything.